# Sort dataframe columns value by close it to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I need the 'value' column of pandas dataframe to be sorted by how close it is to the 'target' value:

```
+----------+---------+----------+
| company  |   value |   target |
|----------+---------+----------+
| A        |   23.18 |  26.8879 |
| B        |   14.31 |  17.8298 |
| C        |   26.08 |  28.5479 |
| D        |   49.82 |  45.4238 |
| E        |   37.38 |  32.136  |
| F        |    3.92 |  11.7219 |
+----------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on the absolute difference of the two columns:

```
import numpy as np
out = df.iloc[np.argsort(df['value'].sub(df['target']).abs())]
```

Or, as a chained command using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df.sort_values(by='value', key=lambda x: x.sub(df['target']).abs())
```

Output:

```
  company  value   target
2       C  26.08  28.5479
1       B  14.31  17.8298
0       A  23.18  26.8879
3       D  49.82  45.4238
4       E  37.38  32.1360
5       F   3.92  11.7219
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually create the dependent column and sort directly on that:

```py
print(
    df.eval('absval = abs(target - value)')
    .sort_values('absval')
)

     company  value   target  absval
2  C          26.08  28.5479  2.4679
1  B          14.31  17.8298  3.5198
0  A          23.18  26.8879  3.7079
3  D          49.82  45.4238  4.3962
4  E          37.38  32.1360  5.2440
5  F           3.92  11.7219  7.8019
```